# Оптимизировать SQL запрос, сократив количество вложенных подзапросов

Tags: sql

### подскажите, можно ли как-то оптимизировать этот запрос, чтобы уменьшить количество подзапросов. Спасибо.

Суть: поиск сотрудника с наибольшим количеством транзакций в таблице с транзакциями. Вывод его имени и отделения

```
select 
  FIRST_NAME, 
  LAST_NAME, 
  DEPARTMENT.Name as DEPARTMENT, 
  count(txn_id) as 'Count_of_trans' 
from 
  acc_transaction 
  join employee e on TELLER_EMP_ID = EMP_ID 
  join DEPARTMENT on e.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID 
group by 
  FIRST_NAME, 
  LAST_NAME, 
  DEPARTMENT.Name 
having 
  count(txn_id)=(
    select 
      max(Count_of_trans) as 'MAX_count_of_trans' 
    from 
      (
        Select 
          TELLER_EMP_ID, 
          count(txn_id) as 'Count_of_trans' 
        from 
          acc_transaction 
        group by 
          TELLER_EMP_ID
      ) t1
  )
```

Comment: Убрать having, весь, вместо него добавить `order by Count_of_trans desc` и `limit 1` или аналогичный ограничитель количества записей, используемый в вашем диалекте SQL

Comment: Звучит действительно логичнее и быстрее. Но в SQL Server такие изменения на 20мс замедлило статистику запроса, в чем может быть дело?